# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - log/application.log (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, docker, passenger, docker-compose

Hi I am using docker to deploy my rails app using phusion/passenger image. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:0.9.19

# set correct environment variables
ENV HOME /root
ENV RAILS_ENV production

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Expose Nginx HTTP service
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx / Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Remove the default site
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Add the nginx site and config
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
ADD rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf

# Let ensure these packages are already installed
# otherwise install them anyways
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential \
                                         nodejs \
                                         libpq-dev

# bundle gem and cache them
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

# Add rails app
ADD . /home/app/webapp
WORKDIR /home/app/webapp


RUN touch log/delayed_job.log log/production.log log/

RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp
RUN RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

# Clean up APT and bundler when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

I am getting permission issue for `tmp` and `log` files.

```
web_1 | [ 2016-07-19 08:45:12.6653 31/7ff812726700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/app/webapp: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
web_1 |   Error ID: 42930e85
web_1 |   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-9DeJ86.html
web_1 |   Message from application: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - log/logentries.log (Errno::EACCES)
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:628:in `initialize'
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:628:in `open'
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:628:in `open_logfile'
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:584:in `initialize'
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:318:in `new'
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:318:in `initialize'
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/le-2.7.2/lib/le/host/http.rb:37:in `new'
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/le-2.7.2/lib/le/host/http.rb:37:in `initialize'
```

I tried to give `chmod -R 665/775/777 log/` and still didn't fixed the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you touch the files? What if you just `mkdir log/` instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating `log/` directory, I even tried giving `777` permission to that `log` directory after I `mkdir log/`, but it is not woking. This is wierd. :( .
The way I can make it working is by creating all the log files that are needed before I `chown` my project directory. This worked well for my logs but, I am creating random files in `tmp` directory, which are failing :(

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your line `RUN RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` first then `RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp`(after your rake task) So, It should be something like this:

`RUN RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
 RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp`

Comment: Can you explain what is happening, and why it needs to be run in this order?